# how to Prevent Listview from ever scrolling between certain bounds?

Tags: flutter

I've a `initialScrollOffset` in my `ScrollController` set to 100. This allows the top of my `ListView` in my `Scaffold` `body` to appear under my `appBar`. (Desired behaviour, my appbar is transparent). This works fine when the page first loads but I'd like my `ScrollController` to prevent my `listView` from ever scrolling between 0 and 100 and always have an `initialScrollOffset` of 100. `ScrollController has a boolean property` keepScrollOffset` but that doesn't prevent the scroll going from 0-100.  Here is my code so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.25),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 30,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.primaries[index % Colors.primaries.length].withOpacity(0.5),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Item $index'),
              ),
            );
          },
          controller: _scrollController,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 100, keepScrollOffset: true)
      ..addListener(() {
        print("offset = ${_scrollController.offset}");
      });
    super.initState();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add padding to the inner content that scrolls up and down with the items, you can just add `padding` to the `ListView`.

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100)
```

Not necessary to use `ScrollController`.